# Caffe error: can't use pretrained prototxt and caffemodel with caffe.Net

Tags: caffe, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04

I want to use DEX trained net from [here](https://data.vision.ee.ethz.ch/cvl/rrothe/imdb-wiki/). But I'm having the following problem, when I use

```
net = caffe.Net('dex_imdb_wiki.caffemodel', 1, weights='age.prototxt')
```

This is the error log:

> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:307] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 2:1: Invalid control characters encountered in text.
>
> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:307] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 2:22: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 162.
>
> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:307] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 2:22: Message type "caffe.NetParameter" has no field named "VGG_ILSVRC_16_layers".
>
> WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
>
> F0501 15:41:00.689872  5795 upgrade_proto.cpp:90] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: gender.caffemodel
>   *** Check failure stack trace: ***

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and python 3.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the error.
Just change the parameters order to

```
net = caffe.Net('age.prototxt', 1, weights='dex_imdb_wiki.caffemodel')
```